# one column has 2 same rows and I want to show it first

Tags: mysql, sql

In this table one column contain 2 identical rows that is courseId column. There are two rows are same that is 612. Now I want to write a query to show that row as first and remaining rows after that.

### course_mapping_table

[image]

### course table

[image]

### users

[image]

And I have written query like below but its not working.

```
public function gettrendingcourse(){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM
    course c
    INNER JOIN course_student_mapping cm
    ON cm.courseId = c.courseId
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON c.userId = u.userId
    INNER JOIN category s
    ON s.categoryId=c.categoryId
    GROUP BY c.courseId HAVING count(*) >= 1
    ORDER BY cm.courseId DESC ";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
            
    return $query;  
}
```

Comment: You have table category in your query but not in your question. Can you add the sample data as text to your question rather than images which we cannot use (and in some cases may be blocked and not visible).

Comment: I agree with P.Salmon. You should not paste images, but paste the tables as text instead. You can use the `{}` button for simple formatting (or use HTML <pre> and </pre> tags).

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN users u
    ON c.userId = u.userId - this should throw an error , there is no visible userid in course and I suspect the join should be on cm.studentid.

Comment: Well spotted, but this doesn't answer the question and should hence be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause in order to get courses ordered by their number of students:

```
SELECT * 
FROM course c
JOIN course_student_mapping cm ON cm.courseId = c.courseId
JOIN users u ON u.userId = cm.studentid
JOIN category s ON s.categoryId = c.categoryId
ORDER BY 
(
  select count(*) 
  from course_student_mapping cm2
  where cm2.courseid = c.courseid
) DESC, courseid, studentid;
```